# Why is my form handler not running?

Tags: 7, forms

I've created a custom module which creates a form and shows it in a block but whenever I submit it, it just refreshes the page and doesn't seem to execute the submit handler at all.

I'm going crazy trying to get this to work.

I've stripped the code right back but it's still not working.

```
<?php

// declare block info
function paypoint_block_info() {
    $blocks['paypoint_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Paypoint Payment Form'), // block admin title
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

// declare block functions
function paypoint_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'paypoint_block':
            $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('paypoint_form');
            return $block;
            break;
    }

}

function paypoint_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'content-page-form');

    $form['strForename'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
        '#title' => 'Forename',
        '#size' => 30,
        '#maxlength' => 37,
        '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Make a payment'),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-default')),
    );

    return $form;
}

function paypoint_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

}

function paypoint_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['strForename']);
}
```

The validate function seems to get called, just not the submit one. I put `print_r($form)` in the validate function and got this: http://pastebin.com/Yt6T6Cr8

Comment: Is this code in the .module file?

Comment: Yes, paypoint.module. The form renders fine it just does nothing on submit

Comment: set brakepoint on submit function and tell if it jumps in there :)

Comment: I added die('validate'); to the paypoint_form_validate function and that worked, but if I put die('submit'); in paypoint_form_submit it doesn't happen. Is there a way I can check what submit handler it is looking for if not mine?

Comment: @nexus_6 Have you tried adding a watchdog() to the submit handler? Then check the resent logged messages (/admin/reports/dblog) to make sure the function is not firing?

Comment: Also, have to just double check, have you cleared the site cache?

Comment: Yeah, every time I make a change

Comment: @Jance Yes, I added watchdog('status', 'Form submit'); to the submit function and watchdog('status', 'Form validate'); to the validate handler. Only the validate handler appears in the log.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that another module may be interfering with my from, how can I debug what is being called when I click submit?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. I think you might be on to something with your last comment, there might be something interfering with the hook.

One thing you might wanna do is run [module_implements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_implements/7.x) and look for the submit hook. That should give you a list of modules that implement that hook. At the very least you can check to see if there is anything strange going on with those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to point the submit handler in the form function clearly ?

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'paypoint_form_mysubmit';
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect, even if I do add that and change the the submit function name.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that if you overload POST with too many form fields, exceeding your PHP max_post_size, PHP will purge POST. Since that includes submission information, no submission will occur. I had a custom form running in a loop off a database query. If it returns too many rows, the form is too large and cannot be submitted. Doesn't look like that was the problem in this case, but wanted to put it here since people searching for a solution may be running into this.